# PHP placing a image(BMP) on a web service

Tags: php, web-services

Im required to place a image on a web service . i tried using **NuSOAP** libraries but i couldn't figure out how to place a image [Only found complex data types such as structures ]

.. is there any **web service API** in PHP that support this action than `NuSOAP` ?

Comment: What do you mean, place? Upload an image? output an `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to manage to send the data as `Base64` Encoded string